# .Net core middleware httpContext concurrent read and write not supported

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have added a middleware in .Net core which log each api request and response to nLog. It works fine for me, even did not noticed any issue with it.
Today i was trying to make bulk request to API and I received an exception

> Concurrent reads or writes are not supported
>   at `await HttpContext.Request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer,0,buffer.Length)` where buffer is `var buffer= new byte[Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Request.ContentLength)]`

I have some confusion at this level

1. Does .Net core creates separate pipeline for each request. I think yes, as HttpContext.Items are unique to each request cycle.
2. If yes, then why I am receiving concurrent error. As my code, first log the request, then pass context to next middleware and lastly log the response. (Does I am missing something?)

Please if you can share the better way to overcome this issue.

Here is code for reference

```
 public class LoggingMiddleware
{
    readonly ILogger logger;
    readonly RequestDelegate next;
    public LoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<LoggingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        LogRequest(context);
        var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
        using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = responseBody;
            await next(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
            LogResponse(context);
            await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    private async void LogRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        request.EnableRewind();
        var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];
        await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        string requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        context.Items["Request"] = requestBody;     //Request is being used in Nlog config
        logger.LogInformation("Request received ......");       // Some information

        context.Items.Remove("Request");
    }

    private async void LogResponse(HttpContext context)
    {
        var response = context.Response;
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var responseText = await new StreamReader(response.Body).ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        context.Items["Response"] = responseText;
        logger.LogInformation("Returned response for url with status");     // Information
        context.Items.Remove("Response");
    }

}
```

Comment: ASP.NET *always* uses a different thread for different requests. The HttpContext refers to a specific request. This hasn't changed in .NET Core. As for the error - where's the code? Why try to use *another* thread to access the context, when the code already runs on its own thread? Did you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` perhaps? And why are you using `Request.Body` when your method most likely already has access to the request body?

Comment: Post your code in the question itself. Don't post links to unrelated articles - those two articles are about logging, not cross-thread access to HttpContext

Comment: could you have used `_next(context);` instead of `await _next(context);` in middleware ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Aha! I got your point. Yes I am using Async method, it might create problem. I am already using ConfigureAwait(false), but didn't solved. I will try again with sync methods, and hopefully I will fix the issue. For request.Body, as i explained, its a middleware, at this point i can only read request body from httpContext.  Thanks for your response

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` most likely  **caused** the problem. Don't try with sync methods. Post the code. Don't assume ASP.NET Core is broken

Comment: @levent Currently I am using await next(context).ConfigureAwait(false). Will it have any impact

Comment: I have no idea, because you haven't posted any relevant information yet

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Frankly I am still not aware the use of ConfigureAwait in middle ware, but I followed the suggestion from Visual studio to add ConfgureAwait. I will study deep the impact of ConfigureAwait. I will try to upload the code, right now its written on another PC, which does not have access to Internet. But its the same as i mentioned in links. Basic idea is to log request and response for each request.

Comment: normally you should use async method without ConfigureAwait(false)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have added the code. please if you can review

Comment: This code is very different from linked articles. The use of `async void` is a serious bug because such methods *can't* be awaited. You should [avoid async void](https://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/) except for event handlers. The code in them can easily run after a request has ended. If you want to log the request or response text, just pass it to `logger.LogInformation`. There's no reason to store the text in HttpContext

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos The issue is resolved now. I changed all async methods to sync. Can you please post your suggestion in answer so that i can mark it

Comment: My suggestion was to 1) use `async Task` instead of `async void` and *await* those methods and 2) to log the response through the ILogger.LogInformation call, not indirectly through the context